# Заменить маркер места на label (Google autocomplete)

Tags: google-maps-api, autocomplete, google-places-api

Использую Google autocomplete, всё работает.

Но есть задача: в результатах выдачи, вместо маркеров выводить `label` с названием типа места.

Всех типов мест должно быть три: *аэропорт*, *гостиница*, *адрес*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все работает правельно, что вы хотите увидеть?

Comment: @L.Vadim по моему вопрос вполне понятный, человек хочет заменить значок маркера возле места на значок типа места(например самолетик возле аэропортов). Только сделать это не получится, places-api такой возможности не предоставляет. Да и вообще как вы планировали ограничить выдачу только аэропортами, гостиницами и адресами? На данный момент можно ограничить только адресами, либо только местами(всеми), хотя ограничение по группам объектов есть, параметр `componentRestrictions`, но на данный момент он поддерживает только тип объекта "Страны"

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич я это и имел ввиду, что все работает как запланированно